# Definition of the Cantor Function

Tags: general-topology

What is the motivation for defining the cantor function $c(x)$ to be The value of $x$ in base $3$, with digits replaced and interpreted in base $2$?

It seems very arbitrary. I can't understand why.

Edit: I'm mainly interested in why taking middle thirds out of the cantor set is equivalent to expelling all members with a 1 in their base 3 example, so long as the 1 is not followed by zeros.

Comment: I put it under topology.

Comment: Um, because you get an interesting function if you do that.  It was a clever idea!  What's the motivation for defining $e$ to be $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}$?  Because if you defined it as something else, you wouldn't get $e^x$ to be a function which is its own derivative.

Comment: Is there a reason those 2 bases were used?  How does it relate to the cantor set, which is made by removing middle thirds?

Comment: Also, can't the cantor function be defined another way, using an integral of a piecewise function?  Why are the two equivalent?

Comment: It maps the Cantor set onto $[0,1]$ in a monotone increasing fashion.

Comment: It's an uncountable set with $0$ measure.

Comment: Thank you guys for bearing with me.  My real hangup is in trying to figure out why taking out middle thirds in the cantor set is equivalent to taking out base 3 numbers with the digit 1, unless that 1 is followed by zeros.

Comment: Look at $[0,1]$. Because of how ternary works, the numbers in $[0,1/3]$ all have first trit = $0$ (writing $1/3=0.0\bar 2_3$). Numbers in $(1/3, 2/3)$ all have first trit = $1$, and numbers in $[2/3, 1]$ have first trit = $2$ (where 1 is written as $0.222..._3$). A similar pattern holds for the 2nd trit and so on. For each trit, removing the $1$s removes the center third of the intervals from the previous trits.

Comment: @AnalysisStudent I think (but don't take my word for it) that the idea to remove the middle thirds of each line segment of the unit interval in an iterative process came first. It so happens that doing that is equivalent to the collection of numbers between $0$ and $1$ that (not including the exception you pointed out, or cases like $0.\overline{1}$) have no $1$ in their ternary expansion

Comment: Thanks both of you, this makes sense to me now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was not the original definition, but it is a quick-and-easy way of defining the same function. The idea was to form a function whose derivative is $0$ almost everywhere, but still is not constant. To do this, the well-known Cantor set, which has measure $0$, is exploited.

I believe the original definition was recursive, following these lines: $f_0(x) = x$ on [0,1]. Then at each stage $n$, $f_n$ is a "slope-step" function, defined piecewise on a finite partition of [0,1]. On each interval of the partition, $f_n$ is either constant, or else is an increasing line segment. At each partition point the value of $f_n$ from below and above are the same, so $f_n$ is continuous, and also $f_n(0) = 0$ and $f_n(1) = 1$. $f_{n+1}$ is defined as follows:

- On each interval where $f_n$ is constant, $f_{n+1} = f_n$.
- On any interval $[a, b]$ of the partition where $f_n(b) > f_n(a)$, let $h = {f_n(a) + f_n(b) \over 2}$, $f_{n+1}$ is defined on $[a,b]$ by

  - rising from $f_n(a)$ to $h$ on $[a, a+ (b-a)/3]$,
  - staying constant at $h$ on $[a + (b-a)/3, a + 2(b-a)/3]$,
  - and rising from $h$ to $f_n(b)$ on $[a+2(b-a)/3, b]$.

The Cantor-Lesbegue function is $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} f_n$